# Does every $4$-connected nonplanar graph contain a $K_5$-minor?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-minors, planar-graphs

By Kuratowski's theorem, every nonplanar graph contains a (topological) minor of $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$.
But I observed that every time I construct a $4$-connected nonplanar graph, it always contains not only a $K_{3,3}$-minor but also a $K_5$-minor.
Moreover, although I tried many times, I cannot construct a $4$-connected nonplanar graph containing only $K_{3,3}$-minors!
So I want to know whether the following statement is true:

> Every $4$-connected nonplanar graph contains a $K_5$-minor.

Unfortunately, I could not find any references about this topic.
If the statement is true, can you give me a proof?
Or if it's not, can you show me a counterexample?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, this is true and follows from [Wagner's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagner%27s_theorem).  Wagner's theorem asserts that every graph with no $K_5$ minor can be built from $0$-, $1$-, $2$-, and $3$-sums from planar graphs and a fixed $8$ vertex non-planar graph called the [Wagner graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagner_graph).  Since the Wagner graph is not $4$-connected, this implies that every $4$-connected graph with no $K_5$ minor is planar.

Alternatively, there is a short proof provided you are happy to assume Kuratowski's theorem.  The proof idea is to start with a model of $K_{3,3}$ and then use $4$-connectivity to 'augment' the model of $K_{3,3}$ to a model of $K_5$.  See the paper [A Quick Proof of Wagner's Equivalence Theorem](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1112/jlms/s2-3.4.661) by Young.

Comment: Thanks for nice reference! But I cannot understand his paper since it's written in Deutsch... Can you explain a brief sketch of the proof? If it is not easy, I may post another question about it.

Comment: Thanks for editing! Now I fully understood how to prove it.